# Bound on the distance (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $Q\subset\mathbb C$ be a simply connected region and $f:D\to Q$, where $D=\{|z|<1\}$, be a conformal map (analytic, one-to-one and onto), and let $\ell(w) = \mathrm{dist}(w, \partial Q)$, where $w\in Q$. 
Prove that:

$$|f'(z)|(1-|z|^2)\ge \ell(f(z))$$

Comment: Are $z$ and $w$ related? Do you mean $w=f(z)$?

Comment: This inequality is incorrect the way it is stated, take for example $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}z:D\to \frac{1}{2}D$ then at the point zero the inequality is incorrect

Comment: It is true for zero.

Comment: We have $l(0)=1$ and $(1-|0|^2)\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Sorry edited again...

Comment: I believe it is still incorrect take $f(z)=2z:D\to 2D$ then at the point $\frac{3}{4}$ the inequality is incorrect.

Comment: 2*(1-9/16)=14/16,
l(3/2)=1/2=8/16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to show the inequality for $z = 0$. For general $z \in D$, consider $h(\zeta) = f(T(\zeta))$, where

$$T(\zeta) = \frac{\zeta+z}{1+\overline{z}\zeta}.$$

Then $h\colon D \to Q$ is biholomorphic, $h(0) = f(z)$, and

$$h'(0)= f'(z)\cdot T'(0) = f'(z)\cdot (1 - \lvert z\rvert^2).$$

To show the inequality for $z = 0$, it is convenient to use the inverse $g$ of $f$. With $w_0 = f(0)$ we have $g'(w_0)\cdot f'(0) = 1$, so we need to show

$$\lvert g'(w_0)\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{\ell(w_0)}.\tag{1}$$

For any $0 < r < \ell(w_0)$, Cauchy's integral formula for the derivatives yields

$$\begin{align}
\lvert g'(w_0)\rvert &= \left\lvert \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert w-w_0\rvert = r} \frac{g(w)}{(w-w_0)^2}\,dw\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\lvert g(w_0 + re^{i\varphi})\rvert}{\lvert (w_0+re^{i\varphi})-w_0\rvert^2} r\,d\varphi\\
&\leqslant \frac{1}{r},
\end{align}$$

since $\lvert g(w)\rvert < 1$. Letting $r \nearrow \ell(w_0)$ yields $(1)$.